# How does Drupal commerce requests looks like?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Let's assume that I have commerce website on Drupal. There is Drupal Commerce module. I want use api to retrieve complete  orders from my store. Is it possible? I can't find any information how this requests looks like (what is response format etc.). Also I don't need php examples , maybe is there Rest API?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are few ways to do it, from simple to (a bit) complex.

- Since you mention retrieving data only, the simple way is to create a new Views listing out all orders, you can configure this views to render output as XML or as JSON. Module used can be Views data export, or Views datasource.
- The second solution is to create a custom module which use hook_menu to create your custom endpoint URL, which calls a callback function where you can define the output you want

```php
function YOURMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['api/order'] = array(
    'title' => 'API Orders',
    'page callback' => 'YOURMODULE_api_orders_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content')
  );
  $items['api/order/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'API Orders',
    'page callback' => 'YOURMODULE_api_orders_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content')
  );
  return $items;
}

function YOURMODULE_api_orders_callback($order_id = NULL) {
  $order_ids = array();
  if(!is_null($order)) {
    array_push($order_ids, $order_id);
  }

  // Load all orders or only 1 order 
  // We can use commerce_order_load_multiple()  
  // or use EntityFieldQuery() if need a complex logic filtering orders
  $orders = commerce_order_load_multiple($order_ids);
  drupal_json_output($orders);
}
```

- The last solution is to use Services modules, create a custom module and create your custom service where you can define your custom resource - in this case - *commerce_order*. 
  A tutorial to create custom services can be found here https://valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-create-custom-web-services-for-drupal-7-0